# Variables, namespace and classes

Tags: python

Based on the following example how come I can print the var xyz from within a class as I always thought the class was stored in its own namespace.

```
xyz = 123
>>> class test:
...    def __init__(self):
...        pass
...    def example(self):
...        print xyz
...
>>> test().example()
123
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are not stored in their own namespace, instead they define their own namespace, i.e variables defined inside a class are local to it and can't be accessed directly outside of it. But, a class can access variables from global scope if required.

Python uses **LEGB** rule to find the value of a variable:

**L**: Local scope

**E**: Enclosing scope

**G**: Glocal scope

**B**: Built-ins

---

Example of **LEGB**:

```
z = 3
def enclosing():
    y = 2
    def local_func():
        x = 1
        print x        #fetch this from local scope
        print y        #fetch this from enclosing scope
        print z        #fetch this from global scope
        print sum      #fetch this from builtins
    local_func()
enclosing()
```

**output:**

```
1
2
3
<built-in function sum>
```

---

So, in your case as `xyz` is not found in both local and enclosing scope, so global scope is  used to fetch the value.

#### Related to scopes:

[Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

[What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: Great explanation. The details are a bit more complicated (because Python decides whether to access a local, a closure cell, or a global at function compilation time, not run time), but the OP shouldn't have to worry about any of that (unless he's doing something unusual, like `exec`ing new code or modifying `locals` behind the compiler's back).

Answer (score 1):

Classes are not stored in their own namespace. They are stored in the namespace they are defined in; in your case, that's the global namespace of the interpreter session.

Methods within classes can still refer to names in that same namespace.

Perhaps you were confused with the scope *at class definition time*. The class *body* is executed as if it is a function; the local namespace of that function then forms the attributes of the resulting class. You can still reach names from outer scopes from there, however:

```
foo = 'bar'

class Spam(object):
    baz = foo   # works, foo can be referenced

    def ham(self):
        xyz = foo  # works, foo is a global and can be referenced
        xyz = baz  # does **not** work, baz is part of the class now.
        xyz = self.baz or Spam.baz   # these do work
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is in a namespace, but that is besides the point.  Your question is more about accessibility of variables/members.  The class's members are encapsulated, meaning that access is through the class.

xyz is in global namespace.  This means that the variable is accessible throughout without going through a class.  This is a thing to avoid.  Classes are easy to create (both in defining them and instantiating them).

A namespace is easier to understand as simply being the name that is pre-pended to the classes contained within that namespace.  Thought of this way, much more remains class-focused, a primary goal of OOP.