# Why wont python return this variable, how can i get it to work?

Tags: python

When I run the following program it prints "2" and then "1" when i want it to print "2" and then "2". What have i done wrong?

```
def thingy(a):
    a= a + 1
    print(a)
    return a
a=1
thingy(a)
print(a)
```

Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: Why are you returning `a` and then throwing it away?

Comment: Useful reading to help understand Python names, values, and function calls: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: you need to understand how Python works:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792596/variables-namespace-and-classes

Answer (score 7):

You haven't re-assigned the `a` variable in your global scope. The `a` variable in the global scope isn't the same as in the function. To be more clear, look at this:

```
def thingy(arg):
    arg = arg + 1
    print(arg)
    return arg


a=1           # Assign a to 1
thingy(a)     # Do some work without altering variable
print(a)      # Print a, which is 1...
a = thingy(a) # Here, a will be equals to two now.
```

#### With global option

You can also edit the global scope by adding `global a` at the beginning of the function and don't pass any argument to the function:

```
def thingy():
    global a
    a= a + 1
    print(a)
    return a
a=1
thingy()
print(a)
```

But prefer the first method, more cleaner.

Comment: What if I want to change two variables?

Comment: See my updated response with global. You can use many global variable with `global a,b,c`.

Answer (score 1):

You have remember that variables in functions are only in scope inside the function. So when you create this function:

```
def thingy(a):
    a= a + 1
    print(a)
    return a
```

`a` is only in scope inside the function. No changes made to it exist outside the function. To use the returned value of a function you need to set a variable to be equal to the result of the function. So the `a` in the function and the `a` outside the function are not the same variable. Example:

```
def foo(a):
    a = 2
    return a

a = 1 #set a = 1
foo(a) #use a in function
```

`a` will still be one since the a inside the function is now out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
a = thingy(a)
print(a)
```

although it may look like you're setting a to 2 in the method, the scope is completely different. Imagine if you'd named the variable in the method b instead. They're different variables with the same name because of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Being a number your 'a' variable that you pass to thingy function is immutable and thus all manipulations inside your functions will not be passed back to original a. Though if you pass a as a list and change it in the function then you'll see all the changes you've made to the list after returning from a function.

```
def thingy(a):
    a[0]= a[0] + 1
    print(a[0])

a=[0]
thingy(a)
print(a[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mistaken with the a's. 
functions live in their own world. they use vars of themselves. unless you tell them to use a global var.

you have lots of options to fix this:

1. use "global" to tell the function to use the global a.

   ```
   def thingy(a):
       global a;
       a= a + 1
       print(a)
       return a
   ```

   just by adding the line "global a" you tell the function "hey, you are not alone - use everyone's a". 
   the problem is that in your script, you use a as a global variable, and as the argument the function take. instead, write:

   def thingy():
   because you don't need the argument anymore.

   so your code will look like this:

   ```
   def thingy():
       global a;
       a= a + 1
       print(a) #You don't need the "return a", you don't use it.
   a=1
   thingy()
   print(a)
   ```
2. Use the return.
   instead of using a global var, you can set "a" to whatever the function returns.

   so instead of just calling thingy(a), use:

   ```
   a = thingy(a)
   ```

   I will use variable called "b" inside the function.

   ```
   def thingy(b):
       b = b + 1
       print(b)
       return b
   a = 1
   a = thingy(a)
   print(a)
   ```